# How AICc deals with nominal vs. numerical variables in linear models?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

Today, I have a question regarding the handling of *numerical and nominal variables inside linear models*, which I aim *to compare* to each other *with  Second-order Akaike Information Criterion* (`AICc`, package:  'MuMIn') for small n.

Here is some made-up data and preparational code:

```
library(MASS)
library(MuMIn)

set.seed(123)
treatments <- c(rep(paste0('t', 1:6), each = 3)) # nominal variable
x <- abs(rnorm(mean = 9500,n = 18,sd = 20000)) # observation
var3 <- runif(n=18, min = 100, max=1000)
var2 <- rnorm(n = 18, mean = 50)
var1 <- c(runif(n=3, min = 80, max=100), # numerical dummy variable for t1
      runif(n=3, min = 65, max=85),  # t2
      runif(n=3, min = 75, max=90), # t3
      runif(n=3, min = 15, max=50), # t4
      runif(n=3, min = 0, max=20), # t5
      runif(n=3, min = 30, max=60)) #t6
boxplot(var1~treatments) # well-separated for each treatment: use as dummy
dat <- data.frame(x, var1, var2, var3, treatments)
```

Explanation: We have an observation, for which we would like to know the effects of treatments 1-6. The data contain a nominal variable for the different treatments and by chance we have a numerical variable, which could be used as a dummy/proxy for the single treatments.

Here comes the linear modeling:

```
lm.nominal.1 <- lm(formula = x~treatments, data = dat)
qqnorm(rstudent(lm.nominal.1)); qqline(rstudent(lm.nominal.1)) # does not look too well
plot(rstudent(lm.nominal.1)~fitted(lm.nominal.1)) ; abline(h=0, col='red') # same here

# so let's log-transform:
 lm.nominal.1.log <- lm(formula = log(x)~treatments, data = dat)
qqnorm(rstudent(lm.nominal.1.log)); qqline(rstudent(lm.nominal.1.log)) # much better
plot(rstudent(lm.nominal.1.log)~fitted(lm.nominal.1.log)) ; abline(h=0, col='red') # same here

# ... in accordance to above
lm.nominal.2.log <- lm(formula = log(x)~treatments+var2, data = dat)
lm.nominal.3.log <- lm(formula = log(x)~treatments+var2+var3, data = dat)

lm.numeric.1.log <- lm(formula = log(x)~var1, data = dat) 
lm.numeric.2.log <- lm(formula = log(x)~var1+var2, data = dat)
lm.numeric.3.log <- lm(formula = log(x)~var1+var2+var3, data = dat)
```

Here comes the Akaike's Criterion:

```
AICc.nominals <- AICc(lm.nominal.1.log, lm.nominal.2.log, lm.nominal.3.log)
AICc.nominals

AICc.numerics <- AICc(lm.numeric.1.log, lm.numeric.2.log, lm.numeric.3.log)
AICc.numerics

AICc.all <- AICc(lm.nominal.1.log, lm.nominal.2.log, lm.nominal.3.log,
             lm.numeric.1.log, lm.numeric.2.log, lm.numeric.3.log)    
# Now further model / likelihood analysis:
AICc.all$Deltai <- AICc.all$AICc - min(AICc.all$AICc)
AICc.all$Weights <- Weights(AICc(lm.nominal.1.log, lm.nominal.2.log, 
lm.nominal.3.log,lm.numeric.1.log, lm.numeric.2.log, lm.numeric.3.log))
```

## Now, let me rephrase my question:

Is it okay to compare linear models containing a numerical dummy variable to linear models containing the nominal variable? Or is it like comparing apples and oranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lm` does dummy encoding internally. If you do it manually, you get exactly the same result:

```
fit1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris)
fit2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ model.matrix(fit1), iris)
AIC(fit1, fit2)
#  df     AIC
#fit1  4 231.452
#fit2  4 231.452
```

So, yes, it is okay.

Comment: That was quick and gives a much better (shorter) example! Do you have any source at hand, which one could cite from?

Comment: `help("lm")` references Chambers (1992) but I don't have immediate access to a copy.

Comment: I unchecked, because of the follwowing:  _"Furthermore, AICc cannot be used to compare models where the data are ungrouped in one case (Model U) and grouped (e.g., grouped into histograms classes) in another
(Model G)_"  (Burnham and Anderson, 2003: Model selection and multimodel inference)

Comment: I just don't understand, if it makes a difference? One could say the observations are grouped (in treatments), but if 'lm' does dummy encoding before, I don't know..

Comment: Why are you suddenly referring to binning when your question is about dummy encoding of factors? These are orthogonal issues.